# UI fix possibly needed for posting jobs to SO Careers

Tags: discussion

I just noticed this job listing on the Careers sidebar today:

[image: accidental lowball salary]

I'm fairly certain this company didn't intend to post a job opening with a salary range of $1 - $2. Seeing it suggests to me that it would be a good idea to take a close look at the interface used by recruiters and companies that create these job listings. I don't use the interface, so I can't give any meaningful suggestions, but it may be a good idea for someone to look over the interface and consider improvements.

At the very least, perhaps someone on the SO staff could reach out to this company and let them know that their salary offer is certainly listed incorrectly. The complete job posting is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112319/senior-quality-assurance-engineer-portland-downtown?med=clc&ref=large-sidebar-tag-themed-python